# Issue looping through a hash, checking for value and saving to empty hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, hash

I'm attempting pull json data from an api,  iterate through a hash of JSON data, append the new data to an empty hash and then check the pulled data for whether the key 'next_page' has any value..breaking the loop if the value is returned nill. I'm pulling the first batch of data from the api successfully, but my loop seems to be incorrect as no data is being inserted into the empty hash i've created.

Any ideas would be deeply appreciated. Thanks for giving my question a read!

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'


#imports APR User data from the zendesk api and populates the database with it. 


uri = URI.parse("https://tester.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request.basic_auth("cbradford@tester.com", "tester32")

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

@response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
puts @response.body
puts @response.message
puts @response.code

res = @response.body
users = res["users"]
data = {}

if users["next_page"]
 newUri = users.fetch('next_page')  
 uriLoop = URI.parse(newUri)
 request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uriLoop)
 request.content_type = "application/json"
 request.basic_auth("cbradford@tester.com", "tester32")

 req_options = {
   use_ssl: uriLoop.scheme == "https",
 }

 @responseLoop = Net::HTTP.start(uriLoop.hostname, uriLoop.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
  end

  resLoop = JSON.parse(@responseLoop.body)
  puts resLoop
  users = resLoop["users"]
  data.concat(users)
end


puts data
puts "hash created Successfully!"
```

Comment: “saving to empty hash”—`data` is an array, not a hash.

Comment: That was a typo, thank you. Same issue still exists, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always omit the first fetched users. Before checking for the presence of `next_page` you never store the fetched users, and thus `data` remains empty.

See here:

```
users = res["users"]
data = {}  ## ---data is initialised but never filled? 

if users["next_page"]
```

Secondly I suspect that `res["users"]` is an array, and since you write `data.concat(users)` later that actually `data` should also be an array.

So your code should be fixed be replacing the above mentioned three lines as follows:

```
data = res["users"]

if users["next_page"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer nathanvda! 
I made data an empty array so that I could use it in the If loop to store data from the response.body in the 'users' variable. 

I will give your fix a shot though, and I appreciate it. Will update if it works for me.